# Button OnClick method not being executed ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I have a simple web form page with a button. I've tried to set up my button as such:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CompletePurchase.aspx.cs" Inherits="Something.Something" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Click!</h2>
    <asp:Button ID="ConfirmBtn" runat="server" Text="Confirm" OnClick="ConfirmBtn_Click1" />    
</asp:Content>
```

And in my code behind:

```
 protected void ConfirmBtn_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //do something
        }
```

I've breakpointed the code behind but it is never hit. Considering this seems like such a basic function of ASP.NET, I have no idea what could be going wrong. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes, removing the button and then adding it again can help.

Comment: Not reproducible...

Comment: Hit F12 in the browser, show the network tab and mark all options to check if it is doing the postback. Also check for javascript errors.

Comment: You should add a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a validator (like a RequiredFieldValidator or something) in the master that prevents the post? You can check it by putting CausesValidation="false" on the button:

```
 <asp:Button ID="ConfirmBtn" runat="server" Text="Confirm" OnClick="ConfirmBtn_Click1" CausesValidation="false" />
```

Comment: Ive been looking through my master and can't see anything like that, in addition to setting `CausesValidation = "false"` in my button code. Unfortunately no joy

Comment: try putting a breakpoint in the onload method of the master and onload method of the page to check the postback is working

Comment: @James the master page has a form tag and the placeholder it's inside it?

Comment: hm,  now I think about it, the master page doesn't have a form tag. I remember removing it for a reason that is now redundant. I'll add the tags back now.

Comment: Adding the master form tags back breaks all my other pages to the point that I can't test to see if this fixes the problem asked I'm afraid Looking into why

Comment: with only a one form tag in the master should be enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143417/discussion-between-david-and-james).